# biblatex : Book with the same title as MVBook

Tags: biblatex

So, question completely changed because the comments got me on the right track, and updated again (the example is a bit harder now, I think).
But maybe I'm not using MVBook correctly ?

Here we go:
In the case of a multi-volume book with volumes that have the same titles to which just a volume number is added, I'm looking for an elegant solution. The standard cite commands do not seem to print the volume number, leading to ambiguous citations if the titles of the volumes are the same.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\makeatletter
%% Biblatex %%
\usepackage[style=verbose-trad2,%
related=true,%
backend=biber]%
{biblatex}% 


\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}

@MVBook{Feynman_Lectures,
  author =   {Richard P. Feynman AND Robert B. Leighton AND Matthew Sands},
  title =    {The Feynman lectures on physics},
  publisher =    {Addison-Wesley Publishing Company},
  volumes = {3},
  year =     1977,
  address =      {Reading, MA.}
}

@Book{Feynman_LecturesI,
  title =    {The Feynman lectures on physics},
  subtitle = {mainly mechanics, radiation and heat},
  volume = {1},
  crossref = {Feynman_Lectures}
}

@Book{Feynman_LecturesII,
  title =    {The Feynman lectures on physics},
  subtitle = {mainly electromagnetism and matter},
  volume = {2},
  crossref = {Feynman_Lectures}
}

\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\makeatother


\begin{document}

\title{Titre}


\author{A. Teur}

\maketitle

First volume\footcite{Feynman_LecturesI}

Second volume\footcite{Feynman_LecturesII}

And the first again\footcite{Feynman_LecturesI}


\end{document}
```

The third citation reads :

Idem, The Feynman lectures on physics, op. cit.

Which is clearly not what it should be. I think one should force citations of books that are part of a MVBook to have the volume number printed each time the title gets printed, but only if the overall title and the volume title are the same.

I could add a "I", "II", etc to the title field of each of the volumes, but this looks redundant in the first citation of a volume :

Richard P. Feynman, Robert B. Leighton, and Matthew Sands. The Feynman lectures on physics. Vol. 1: The Feynman lectures on physics I. mainly mechanics, radiation and heat. 3 vols. Reading, MA.: Addison-Wesley Publishing Company, 1977.

Comment: `@book` is for single-volume books specifically. In particular, it expects a `title` field. However, yours does not have such a field so there is nothing to be printed for the title and that is what you get. Note that your example is much more complex than it needs to be. For one thing, `\citetitle` is enough to show that it has nothing to do with using footnotes. Or `babel` or `perpage` or `memoir` etc.

Comment: Though you might feel that there is some redundancy there, I would urge you to add `title = {Nietzsche I}` to `MH_NietzscheI`, `@book`s need a `title` field to function properly.

Comment: There is an ad-hoc solution to your problem (by redefining some internal macros), but I doubt that would be a good idea. Note that because you use `crossref` in `MH_NietzscheI`, you can make the entry more compact by avoiding redundancies:
`@Book{MH_NietzscheI,
  crossref = {MH_Nietzsche},
  volume = {1},
  title = {Nietzsche I},
}` should be enough (modulo line breaks).

Comment: Yes, indeed, it seems I didn't get it quite right, and I shouldn't have called the working example minimal. But you've got me on the right track; it has nothing to do with footcites; I was probably trying to avoid redundancies when I made this bib entry a long time ago. Now, if I just add `title = {Nietzsche}`, it doesn't create a redundancy in the first cite command, the reason I would like to avoid `title = {Nietzsche I}` . However, maybe I could force biblatex to print the volume as well when it prints the title... let's see if I can change this macro...

Comment: One can certainly change the macros (the relevant macro is `cite:title`, ll. 144-148 in `verbose-trad2.cbx`) to include the `volume`, but I really feel that this solution has an ad-hoc character.

Comment: Yes, but "Nietzsche. T. 1 : Nietzsche I. 2 t." in the first citation looks a bit silly... and it looks even sillier when the title is longer, as in "The Feynman Lectures on Physics". In these "Lectures", each volume has a subtitle, but that's certainly not what one can use as a title in a citation. Thanks for the exact reference to the code, I always loose a lot of time lokking for the right file and place!

Comment: I started looking, but I got stuck when trying to implement a test whether or not the booktitle and the mvbooktitle are the same. To do it correctly, only if they are the same, a volume number should be printed... I think. So if this is peanuts for you, @moewe, please go ahead!

Comment: One cool capability of `biblatex` I just got reminded of can be seen when specifying the gender of the authors (here `gender = {pm}`: plural male would be right): Watch how the "idem" magically transform into (the grammatically correct) "eidem".

Comment: Cool indeed, I'll give it a try. Thanks for answering!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The relevant macro for short subsequent citations in `verbose-trad2` is `cite:title`. We just modify it to include the `volume` if `maintitle` and `title` coincide.

```
\renewbibmacro*{cite:title}{%
  \printtext[bibhyperlink]{%
    \printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle}%
    \iffieldsequal{maintitle}{title}
      {\setunit{\addcomma\space}%
       \printfield{volume}}
      {}
    \setunit{\nametitledelim}%
    \bibstring[\mkibid]{opcit}}}
```

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[style=verbose-trad2,
backend=biber]
{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}

@MVBook{Feynman_Lectures,
  author =   {Richard P. Feynman AND Robert B. Leighton AND Matthew Sands},
  title =    {The Feynman lectures on physics},
  publisher =    {Addison-Wesley Publishing Company},
  volumes = {3},
  year =     1977,
  address =      {Reading, MA.}
}

@Book{Feynman_LecturesI,
  title =    {The Feynman lectures on physics},
  subtitle = {mainly mechanics, radiation and heat},
  volume = {1},
  crossref = {Feynman_Lectures}
}

@Book{Feynman_LecturesII,
  title =    {The Feynman lectures on physics},
  subtitle = {mainly electromagnetism and matter},
  volume = {2},
  crossref = {Feynman_Lectures}
}

\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\renewbibmacro*{cite:title}{%
  \printtext[bibhyperlink]{%
    \printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle}%
    \iffieldsequal{maintitle}{title}
      {\setunit{\addcomma\space}%
       \printfield{volume}}
      {}
    \setunit{\nametitledelim}%
    \bibstring[\mkibid]{opcit}}}

\begin{document}
First volume\footcite{Feynman_LecturesI}.

Second volume\footcite{Feynman_LecturesII}.

And the first again\footcite{Feynman_LecturesI}.
\end{document}
```

[image]